# Seeking a formula to scale a variable in one range (eg, $-5000$ to $5000$) to another (eg, $0$ to $5000$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Is it possible to scale a variable that is given in a range of, say, $-5000$ to $5000$, into a range from $0$ to $5000$?

I have tried using the following scaling formula but it doesn't seem to work for either positive or negative numbers, where $x$ is the variable, and $a$ and $b$ are the scaled range of $0$ to $5000$:

$$
x_{scaled} = (b-a)\frac{x - min(x)}{max(x) - min(x)} + a 
$$

Comment: your formula does work on either positive or negative numbers. In your case, it would simplify to $x_{scaled} = \frac{x + 5000}{2}$

Comment: "*but it doesn't seem to work.*"  Clarify why you think that

Comment: Woops, I have no idea what I have been doing, it does work. Thanks anyway folks!

Comment: @Nephanth Also thanks for the simplification.